# Keep getting key not found when using AWS S3 CopyObject command

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

Getting the following error when trying to use the copyObject command (AWS S3). I'm using the AWS PHP SDK, and here is the code:

```
$this->client->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => 'lms-courses',
    'Key'        => 'ideasfile.zip',
    'CopySource' => "lms-courses/lalala.zip",
));
```

> Error executing "CopyObject" on
>   "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/lms-courses/ideasfile.zip"; AWS
>   HTTP error: Client error: `PUT
>   https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/lms-courses/ideasfile.zip` resulted
>   in a `404 Not Found` response:
>   `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not
>   exist.lalala.zipE698888 (truncated...)
>   NoSuchKey (client): The specified key does not exist. -
>   `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not
>   exist.lalala.zipE698888912B810F7DfHtqN5Hls4hGdTGY/pVv36XZPzoM4mJ5fAdhJjEjDufNUArvKCrqN27SjiG06u5hnC8G8yPdzA=

I've been struggling with this error for awhile now. The bucket `lms-courses` exists, and so does `ideasfile.zip`. I even manually added that file into the bucket, just to test it out that way - in case that it didn't upload properly or something.

I don't get why it says that the key does not exist, when it clearly does - I am looking at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says the source object `lalala.zip` does not exist. Are you sure `lms-courses/lalala.zip` exists?

According to [Copy an Object Using the AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html)

```
// Copy an object.
$s3->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => $targetKeyname,
    'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
));
```

Comment: Omg, I had that thing backwards the whole time - ideasfile.zip and lalala.zip need to be swapped. I am an idiot.